# Response Header missing in IIS Server for a static json file

Tags: json, iis

I have hosted a json file in IIS. I have enabled the MIME type for json also. But While accessing the site I am not getting the proper response header application/json. The status code is 304(Not modified).

I am expecting the status code be 200(OK) and response header as application/json.

Comment: Web servers don't always return 200, so you should start to learn other status codes, such as 304, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304

Comment: This may be caused by caching, so you can clear your browser's cache and try again.